# Must apt behave in the same way, regardless of the order of the packages?

Tags: apt

IMHO, the order of packages should not relevant for apt.
It should always be deterministic.

But I found a difference for three packages on a vanilla debian12 docker image

```bash
docker run --rm -ti debian:12.1
apt update
apt install lxde-core xterm chromium # Fails
apt install lxde-core chromium xterm # works
```

It only depends of the order of the xterm and chromium package, but if I remove one of the three packages it always works (order independent).

If it fails the error is

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  
  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 luit : Breaks: x11-utils (< 7.7+6) but 7.7+5 is to be installed  
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

If I install the packages with `apt install lxde-core chromium xterm # works` the package `luit` isn't installed at all.
`dpkg -l luit x11-utils`

```
un  luit           <none>       <none>       (no description available)  
ii  x11-utils      7.7+5        amd64        X11 utilities
```

luit is only recommended in the xterm package

Is this a bug in apt or in one of the package dependencies?
Should apt detect a *defect* dependency in packages?

Comment: Hmm, `x11-utils` 7.7+5 includes `luit` version 1.1.1, but the separate package `luit` has version 2.0.20221028-1. Looks like `luit` is being split off into its own package in between `x11-utils` versions 7.7+5 and 7.7+6. I'm not enough of a packaging guru to tell how this should have been done, but this might be a partial explanation of why the error might be happening.

Comment: If package A provides B, and also conflicts with B, and one ordering of packages asks for B first (and selects B first) then A, and the other asks for A first (then selects A for providing B), then the two orders will of course have different outcomes.

Comment: I wonder if there's a race condition writing the package info (with the dependencies that have been met) to disk?  What happens when you invoke `apt install lxde-core` and then in a subsequent command, `apt install xterm chromium`?